# When to use Float32Array instead of Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

When does it make sense to use a `Float32Array` instead of a standard JavaScript `Array` for browser applications?

This [performance test](http://jsperf.com/float32array-slowness-test/2) shows `Float32Array` to be, in general, slower - and if I understand correctly a standard `Array` stores numbers as 64bit - so there is no advantage in precision.

Aside from any possible performance hit, `Float32Array` also has the disadvantage of readability - having to use a constructor:

```
a = new Float32Array(2);
a[0] = 3.5;
a[1] = 4.5;
```

instead an array literal

```
a = [3.5, 4.5];
```

I'm asking this because I'm using the library glMatrix which defaults to `Float32Array` - and wondering if there's any reason I shouldn't force it to use `Array` instead which will allow me to use array literals.

Comment: I can't find any site that answers this, my guess is the main benefit is that it uses less memory. So if you're working with huge floating point arrays, it could be a benefit.

Comment: It may have been a language port to JavaScript and Float32Array was the closest to whatever the source language had available.

Comment: The [Typed Array Specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/) may help: "This specification provides an API for interoperability with native binary data".

Comment: You can still use literal-style syntax: `new Float32Array([3.5, 4.5])`. `Float32Array` is significantly slower than `Float64Array` because the values have to be converted to/from 64-bit values anytime you do something with the array's contents, so if memory space allows and you are aiming for speed, try `Float64Array` instead.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I emailed the developer of `glMatrix` and my answer below includes his comments (points 2 & 3):

1. Creating a new object is generally quicker with `Array` than `Float32Array`. The gain is significant for small arrays, but is less (environment dependent) with larger arrays.
2. *Accessing* data from a `TypedArray` (eg. `Float32Array`) is often faster than from a normal array, which means that most array operations (aside from creating a new object) are faster with TypedArrays.
3. As also stated by @emidander, `glMatrix` was developed primarily for WebGL, which requires that vectors and matrices be passed as `Float32Array`. So, for a WebGL application, the potentially costly conversion from `Array` to `Float32Array` would need to be included in any performance measurement.

So, not surprisingly, the best choice is application dependent:

- If arrays are generally small, and/or number of operations on them is low so that the constructor time is a significant proportion of the array's lifespan, use `Array`.
- If code readability is as important as performance, then use `Array` (i.e. use `[]`, instead of a constructor).
- If arrays are very large and/or are used for many operations, then use a TypedArray.
- For WebGL applications (or other applications that would otherwise require a type conversion), use `Float32Array` (or other `TypedArray`).

Comment: "large" and "small" are very vague descriptions that change within different contexts. Can anyone expand a bit what's considered a "very large" array when we talk about Float32Array vs what's very small?

Comment: @yuvi to me "large" means using up significant memory resources. E.g. in node, I made an array of 10,000,000 numbers, and the whole node process took 86MB. With a Float32Array of 10,000,000 node only look 46MB.

Answer (score 8):

I would assume that the glMatrix library uses Float32Array because it is primarily used in WebGL-applications, where matrices are represented as Float32Arrays (http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/#5.14.10).

Answer (score 0):

In today browsers implementation, using Float32Array has impact in both writibility and performance if compared against vanilla Arrays. It seems that even gl-matrix authors agreed that the library need to be refactored to remove Float32Array dependency: https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/issues/359

Comment: This performance impact assumption is not generally correct, it's also [challenged](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/issues/359#issuecomment-523781401) in the GitHub issue you linked. The TL;DR is that rapid unoptimized (re)allocation performs worse with typed arrays, but properly optimized code with memory preallocation performs better with typed arrays. The memory impact of "long" typed arrays (other than float64) is also shorter than the memory impact of "long" regular arrays.

Answer (score 0):

TypedArrays like Float32Array was introduced in JS with the launch of WebGL to have a large bunch of data in an array to feed the GPU memory. Using WebGL is for example not that easy only with common Arrays. FloatArray does not have any benefit over Array in a standard JS application.