# What is the function of GLMAT_ARRAY_TYPE() in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, matrix, opengl-es, webgl

I've been reading through [this](https://github.com/tparisi/webgl-lessons/blob/master/js/gl-matrix-2.2.1.js) WebGL library for Matrix related operations and came across a function on line 2826 where a 4 x 4 matrix object is being created:

```
mat4.create = function() {
    var out = new GLMAT_ARRAY_TYPE(16);
```

where out is the matrix that will be created. I've looked in various places including the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Constants) on Mozilla Developers for WebGL, but I haven't been able to find any information about what this function actually does. What is the purpose of the function?

Comment: *"It doesn't appear to be defined in the library"* ,its right below the shim:
https://github.com/tparisi/webgl-lessons/blob/master/js/gl-matrix-2.2.1.js#L80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its defined here `var GLMAT_ARRAY_TYPE = (typeof Float32Array !== 'undefined') ? Float32Array : Array;`

Basically it will attempt to use Float32Array instead of regular js array when its available. Float32Array is slower to create than regular array but its values can be read much faster than regular array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was just looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823021/when-to-use-float32array-instead-of-array-in-javascript) post where apparently the creator of the library notes that Float32 arrays should be used when working with WebGL. It seems that the impetus is just to avoid the time overhead with the conversion between regular arrays and Float32 arrays since WebGL uses the latter.

Comment: I went to jspref and tested this out again. http://jsperf.com/float32array-slowness-test/10. It seems that creating Float32 is still significantly slower than regular array but reading Float32 is a lot faster than regular array, way more than last time I checked, at least in chrome.