# Storing coords in javascript as a 2D Vector Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, typed-arrays

Which one would be better? (for memory and calculation speed)

1. `new Float32Array(2);`
2. `new Float64Array(2);`
3. `{x: 0, y: 0};`
4. `[0, 0];`

Obviously 1. is more memory efficient than 2, but what about speed? 32 bits calculations will be faster than 64 bits? What about the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823021/when-to-use-float32array-instead-of-array-in-javascript).
`Float32Array`s are used for WebGL apps. 
Also, arrays are always faster than objects, for example that's why [Elm](https://github.com/elm-lang/html) use arrays to construct it's virtual DOM.