# What's the difference between Float64Array and Array<number> in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, what's the functional difference between the types [Float64Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array) and Array?

Typescript doesn't appear to have a specific type for 64-bit floats or doubles, and [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) says the `number` type is used to represent all integers, floats and doubles.

But if that's true, then why does Float64Array exist? Can I replace Float64Array with Array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Float32Array instead of Array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823021/when-to-use-float32array-instead-of-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @Noah, Not exactly, although it's similar. That mostly deals with Float32Array, which has less precision than Array<number>.

Comment: `Array<number>` only exists in Typescript. When it's transpiled it's just array so at runtime you can sneak anything you want in there. This is not true for the Float64Array which will convert anything you put in there to a number at runtime

Answer (score 4):

Since the question is tagged with `typescript`, the high level answer is: because TypeScript is used to represent JavaScript, and JavaScript has both Float64Array and Array. But I suspect the question you're really getting at is this part:

> Typescript doesn't appear to have a specific type for 64-bit floats or doubles, and this says the number type is used to represent all integers, floats and doubles.

TS uses `number` to represent any number that a JS value can be. Since JS is untyped, it's up to the interpreter to represent numbers however they choose within the limits of the spec. Just because a number *can* be a float64, doesn't mean it *has* to be represented by a float64. Some optimizers will spit out code that looks like this:

```
const a = 15 | 0;
```

The bitwise OR operator works by converting both operands to an int32 and returns an int32. Now the JS engine knows that `a` can be internally represented as an integer instead of a float, and it can then perform any integer optimizations whenever it's used later in the code.

---

So regarding Array vs Float64Array, v8 has an [ElementsKind](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/dc712da548c7fb433caed56af9a021d964952728/src/objects/elements-kind.h#L31-L96) enum that is used to represent the content type of a generic Array, whereas Float64Array elements are all treated as floats. For example:

```
const a = [1,2,3];
```

`a` will be internally represented as an `Array<PACKED_SMI_ELEMENTS>` (small integer). If you were to push a new value that isn't an integer to that array, the internal type would transition:

```
a.push(4.5);
// a is now Array<PACKED_DOUBLE_ELEMENTS>
```

More information on element kinds and optimization suggestions can be found in this [v8 dev blog](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds)

Comment: Great v8 dev blog post, I never knew this was going on under the hood. Thanks for sharing!